# Server Error:The selection did not contain any resource that can run on a server

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

I am trying to learn Spring framework with the AOP technology . Therefor, I have created a normal Java project (without Maven) and imported the spring jars `spring` as well the jars of the AOP `AspectJ` (Please see the screen shoot underneath).

Everything worked fine before and I got the output `Circle name`.

But at the next day I tried to run the project again but I am getting the window error `The selection did not contain any resource that can run on a server`. So after the error if I right click the `AopMain` class I do not have the option to run the class on the server. To get the option again, I have to restart the eclipse and start the Tomcat 7  server.

What should I do to fix the error?

**AopMain**

```
package org.stack;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.stack.service.ShapeService;


    public class AopMain {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "file:src/spring.xml");
            ShapeService shapeService =  (ShapeService) ctx
                    .getBean("shapeService", ShapeService.class);
            System.out.println(shapeService.getCircle().getName());
        }

    }
```

**Circle**

```
package org.stack.model;

public class Circle {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**Triangle**

```
package org.stack.model;

public class Triangle {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**ShapeService**

```
package org.stack.service;

import org.stack.model.Circle;
import org.stack.model.Triangle;

public class ShapeService {
    private Circle circle;
    private Triangle triangle;

    public Circle getCircle() {
        return circle;
    }

    public void setCircle(Circle circle) {
        this.circle = circle;
    }

    public Triangle getTriangle() {
        return triangle;
    }

    public void setTriangle(Triangle triangle) {
        this.triangle = triangle;
    }

}
```

**Spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <bean name="triangle" class="org.stack.model.Triangle">
        <property name="name" value="Triangle name"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="circle" class="org.stack.model.Circle">
        <property name="name" value="Circle name"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="shapeService" class="org.stack.service.ShapeService"
        autowire="byName">
    </bean>

    <!--  <bean name="loggingAspect" class="org.stack.aspect.LoggindAdvice"></bean> -->

</beans>
```

**Error**

[image]